# Filtrar con react

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, reactjs, api

Quiero filtrar los resultados de mis 2 peticiones que devuelven un objeto JSON

primer objeto "Preguntas"

```
{
"id" : 1
"pregunta" : ¿Qué animal representa más tu personalidad?
}
```

Segundo objeto "Respuestas"

```
 {
        "id" : "1",
        "id_pregunta" : "1",
        "opcion" : "Oso anteojos"
 },
```

Este es el resultado que tengo
[image: señalo el id correspondiente de cada objeto JSON]

Este es el resultado que obtengo de las Preguntas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero obtener un resultado que agrupe las opciones dependiendo de las preguntas
Ejemplo : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi componete

```
 render(){
        return(

            <div className="cuestionario">    

               <span>{this.props.item.id}</span><span> {this.props.item.opcion}</span> 
               {this.props.item.id_pregunta} {this.props.item.pregunta} 
            </div>

           );
        }
```

en este  componetente le mando los props

```
render(){
  return (
        <div className="app container">
          <div className="config-logo">
                    <img src={LogoBoxi} />
                </div>
          {this.state.opciones.map((opcion, key) =>  
            <Preguntas
             item={opcion} key={key}
            />
          )}
          {this.state.preguntas.map((pregunta, respuesta) =>  
            <Preguntas
             item={pregunta} key={respuesta}
            />
          )}
         <div className="BotonesSeleccion">        
                    <input type="button" value="Volver" />
                    <input type="button" value="Siguiente" />
                </div> 
          </div>
      );

      }
```

Comment: Pero no tendrás unas posibles respuestas para esa pregunta? Es decir la pregunta con el id 1 tendrá X respuestas? Entonces supongo que es eso lo quieres filtrar. Las opciones de la pregunta con el id X? No entendí muy bien tu pregunta.

Comment: la posible respuesta es la imagen de ejemplo que puse, no he podido logar hacer eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que los objetos de las preguntas y de las respuestas te vengan en un array, yo usaría un reducer:

```js
const preguntas = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "pregunta" : "¿Qué animal representa más tu personalidad?"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "pregunta" : "¿Qué animal representa menos tu personalidad?"
    },
];
const respuestas = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "id_pregunta" : 1,
        "opcion" : "Oso anteojos"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "id_pregunta" : 2,
        "opcion" : "Ornitorrinco"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "id_pregunta" : 1,
        "opcion" : "Gato"
    },
];

const preguntaYRespuestas = preguntas.reduce((acc, elemento)=>{
    const respuestasFiltradas = respuestas.filter((resp)=>elemento.id === resp.id_pregunta);
    return [...acc, { ...elemento, respuestas: respuestasFiltradas }];
}, []);

console.log(preguntaYRespuestas);
```

Y tus dos componentes, se podría reducir a uno:

```js
render(){
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.preguntasYRespuestas.map((pregunta)=>(
                      <div>
                        <div key={pregunta.id}>{pregunta.pregunta}</div>
                        <div>
                            {
                                pregunta.respuestas.map((respuesta)=>(
                                    <div key={`${pregunta.id}_${respuesta.id}`}>{respuesta.opcion}</div>    
                                ))
                            }
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        );
  
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, se que me servira de mucho tu respuesta